# ASP.NET Core app with Angular in Visual Studio - API does not run

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been following this [tutorial (Create an ASP.NET Core app with Angular in Visual Studio)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022),

After following all the steps and running the solution at the end, it seems the Angular project is running successfully, however, the API doesn't run.  I've tried hitting the API endpoint via postman and the breakpoints within Visual Studio are never hit.

From the angular app, within dev tools I see 504 Gateway Timeout when hitting `https://localhost:4200/weatherforecast`

Has anyone experienced this before? if so, how do you fix it?

I tired what is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72415856/angular12-with-net6-webapi-error-econnrefused-error-occurred-while-proxying), but the outcome is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve, seems I'm running the latest version of `Nodejs` which isn't support, ended up installing [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and installing a version which was support, in my case v16.13.2

Once installed I then ran, `nvm use 16.13.2`, kicked off the project and voilà it calls the backend api with no issues and displays the data :)

Hope it helps.